# Is a finitely generated torsion module over PID an injective module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Since I often draw wrong conclusions, I need a confirmation.
My argument is that for nonzero prime $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$, $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is injective being a field (hence divisible), and $A/p^{k}$ is its quotient hence again is injective, and the f.g. torsion module is a finite direct sum of such quotients hence is injective.
I couldn't find any book that mentions this fact and I'm wondering I might have made a mistake somewhere.
Thanks!

Comment: $A/\mathfrak{p}^k$ is not a quotient of $A/\mathfrak{p}$, it's the other way around. Since $\mathfrak{p}^k\subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, then $(A/\mathfrak{p}^k)/(\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^k)\cong A/\mathfrak{p}$. Also, fields are not necessarily divisible: fields of finite characteristic are not divisible modules. No finite field is a divisible $\mathbb{Z}$-module (and for that matter, neither is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for any $n\gt 1$).

Comment: P.S. "fields of finite characteristic are not divisible module" should be "divisible $\mathbb{Z}$-modules; they are divisible over themselves. Being a field does not tell you if it is injective as an $R$-module in general.

Comment: Z/2Z is a divisible Z/2Z module, after all it is a field and you can divide by any nonzero field element.  But "nonzero" for the field and "nonzero" for the ring might differ.  Z/2Z is not a divisible Z-module, because it is not divisible by 2!

Comment: You have an argument... But have you considered any example at all?

Comment: This question arose from reading Dummit's Algebra where he talks about finitely generated modules over PID. For some reason he calls the p-torsion part a "p-primary component" of the module. I was trying to find a connection with primary decomposition. The only connection I know, the equivalence between primary docomposition of a submodule and direct sum decomposition of the injective hull of its quotient in terms of indecomposable injectives, seemed to work if the module is injective, but now I see it was a bad guess...

Comment: Every torsion module over a 1-dimensional domain (like a PID) is a direct sum of its p-torsion parts.  Be careful that injective hulls can decompose quite a lot, even if the original module is indecomposable. However, in the case of torsion modules over a PID, the decomposition is very similar, so your intuition is probably fine there.

Comment: The Z-module Z/2Z is not divisible by 2, but if you tried to divide it by 2, you'd get Z/4Z.  2Z/4Z ≅ Z/2Z, so that's good.  However, Z/4Z is still not divisible by 2.  If you tried to divide it by 2, you'd get Z/8Z. 2Z/8Z ≅ Z/4Z.  However, ...  If you keep this up you finally get to the module Z[1/2]/Z, the Prüfer quasi-cyclic 2-group.  It is an injective module, and is the injective hull of Z/2Z.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to check statements about injective modules is to see what's happening for $\mathbb{Z}$-modules -- i.e., abelian groups.  (In general, it's a good idea to test out statements of the form "does this property of modules/rings/spaces/... imply this other property?" by considering relatively simple, well-understood examples.  But I don't want to preach too much...)

For $R = \mathbb{Z}$, there is the following nice criterion (due, I believe, to R. Baer): a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ is injective iff it is a **divisible** group: i.e., for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, the map $x \mapsto nx$ is surjective.  (Here I am writing the group law on $M$ additively, as is traditional.)

From this it is easy to see that any nonzero injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module must be infinite.  Indeed, if $M$ is finite, then multiplication by $n = \# M$ on $M$ is identically zero.

For that matter, no (nonzero) finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module is injective.  The simplest example of an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module is probably $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ (i.e., the additive group of the rational field).  Since quotients of divisible groups are divisible, also $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible.  The first example is torsion-free, and the second example is torsion.  These examples give the flavor of the general case.

**Added**: Actually Baer's Criterion extends to all modules over PIDs as follows: for a ring $R$, an $R$-module $M$ is **divisible** if for all $r \in R \setminus \{0\}$, the endomorphism $r \cdot$ of $M$ is surjective.  (This is a direct generalization of the notion of divisible $\mathbb{Z}$-module.)  Then it follows from another basic result of Baer that a module over any PID is injective iff it is divisible.  I learned this on wikipedia (which is getting better and better at math, I must say): [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Baer.27s_criterion).

Note that applying this criterion of Baer immediately gives the following fact: if $R$ is a PID of characteristic $0$ (equivalently, the natural map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ is an injection), then an injective $R$-module must also be an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  In particular no finite $R$-module is injective.

Answer (score 6):

You can have an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow Z/2Z \rightarrow Z/4Z \rightarrow Z/2Z \rightarrow 0$, where the maps are inclusion and projection. Then this sequence does not split, since $Z/4Z$ is not isomorphic to $Z/2Z \oplus Z/2Z$. Therefore $Z/2Z$ is not injective.